# can we iterate over two lists with purrr (not simultaneously)?

Tags: r, purrr

Consider that I have a function `f(x,y)` that takes two argument and two lists

- `x_var = list('x','y','z')`
- and `y_var = list('a','b')`

Is there a `purrr` function that allows me to iterate every combination of one element in `x_var` and one element in `y_var`? That is, doing `f(x,a)`, `f(x,b)`, `f(y,a)`, `f(y,b)` etc.

The usual solution would be to write a loop, but I wonder if there is more concise here (possibly with `purrr`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use one of the `cross*` functions along with `map`:

```
map(cross2(x_var, y_var), unlist)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can nest your calls to `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(x_var, function(x) {
  map(y_var, paste, x)
})
[[1]]

[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a x"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "b x"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a y"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b y"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "a z"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "b z"
```

Answer (score 5):

The base R function `expand.grid` function works here

```
expand.grid(x=x_var, y=y_var) %>% {paste(.$x, .$y)}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `x_var` and `y_var` are atomic vectors or arrays, and the function returns an atomic vector of known length, you can use the base R function `outer`:

```
outer(x_var, y_var, FUN = f)
```

This will return an array with dimensions `c(dim(x_var), dim(y_var))`. Dimension names are similarly combined. For example:

```
x_var <- setNames(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"))
y_var <- setNames(4:5, c("d", "e"))
outer(x_var, y_var, '+')
#   d e
# a 5 6
# b 6 7
# c 7 8
```

Comment: nice one! I wonder if there is the equivalent in the tidyverse? I like the output matrix of it